# Bisection method returns "missing value where true false needed", can't replicate error

Tags: r

In my bisection algorithm, it says that there's a "missing value where true/false is needed", and it points to this line:

```
if (sign(f(c)) == sign(f(a))  ) {
  a <- c

}
```

Why? There's nothing wrong with that line, and if I replicate it manually, it works just fine. Yet when I run the function, it produces

```
Error in if (sign(f(c)) == sign(f(a))) { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

EDIT: Full code is

```
Bisection <- function(f, a,b, tol = 0.005, maxiter = 1000) {
i <- 1
while (i < maxiter) {
c <- (a+b)/2
if (f(c) == 0 | (b-a)/2 < tol) { return(c)}
i <- i + 1
if (sign(f(c)) == sign(f(a))  ) {
  a <- c

}
else {b <- c}}
return(NA)
```

}

Always, 0 and 100 are used as a and b.

I'm calling the function on different functions f, that are the same except for a different parameter, and it is only for one very particular parameter that the bisection function fails. For all other parameters, the bisection function works fine.

Comment: Add `f`, `c`, and `a` to your question.

Comment: Are `f`, `c`, and `a` all arguments passed into your function? How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the  `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` means R is encountering an NA value - in this case, I would expect an NA value in either `a`, `c`, or whatever `f()` returns for these values.

It could be that when you run these lines manually, the values stored in your global environment for `a` and `c` are just fine (non-missing), but whatever values are passed into your function (or computed within it) contains missing values.  I'd recommend checking that.